# Showing ProgressDialog but obtain odd result

Tags: android

Anyone know what happen to the ProgressDialog? It alwasy be showed like the picture below:

[image]

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
dialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait...");
dialog.show();
```

Why? Anyone know?

Comment: One more question, what happen to the ProgressDialog class API doc in android reference. Most of the functions have empty content.

Comment: So what you are expecting it to be?

Answer (score 1):

i think this because the spinner theme, you passed as a second parameter to the PD constructor

try like this:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
pd.setTitle("Downloading...");
pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
pd.show();
```

Comment: oh, you are right. After removed the theme, the panel behind dissapear, but why? The theme should be correct right? What the heck to the API doc, there is no further explanation for the constructor/functions.